# RTX 2070 Super not working on multiple applications

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, performance, nvidia-graphics-card, opengl

I recently got a new Snowblind computer from iBuyPower. Certain games run very slowly (<30FPS) (Rocket League, CS:GO, Valorant), while other applications just don't work now (Blender, OBS, Minecraft). I know it's the CPU (RTX 2070 Super) that's the problem because if I switch each of these applications to use the built-in CPU Graphics Card(Intel HD Graphics 630) which is what I'm doing for now, they run fine but cap out at ~ 40-60 fps which isn't ideal. Minecraft and blender both say "The driver does not appear to support OpenGL" I have uninstalled drivers and installed new drivers, old drivers, reset the drivers, installed Game Ready Drivers, installed Studio Drivers, none of it fixes the error code. I'm willing to supply any needed information(BIOS, etc.) if it's needed. The rest of my specs:
CPU: 8-Core Intel i7-9700k
RAM: Corsair 16 GB
Motherboard: TUF Z390-PRO GAMING

EDIT: I ran the OpenGL Extensions viewer and the program refused to accept the dedicated card, not through the dropdown menu, nor through manually re-assigning the card for the program, the only time it didn't display the Intel 630 was when I manually disabled the integrated graphics card, and then "GDI Generic" appears, but not the RTX. Other than that, the only "renderer" that displays is the Intel 630 UHD Graphics and it says it works fine.

Comment: See https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011375 for how to run OpenGL tests. Add your results to the question.

Comment: Do you know what kind of self-testing you are allowed to do without violating any warranty? It almost sounds like the RTX 2070 GPU is not being found (maybe defective, not seated fully, or lack of power). Before taking advice on opening up the case to check that the card is seated and the power cables are properly attached, I would contact iBuyPower support about to see what they recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Don't know why this worked, but plugging my second monitor into the CPU one and switching the primary monitor to DisplayPort fixed the issue.